# Como hacer predeterminado el número?

Tags: javascript

Solo intento asignar un parámetro como `valor indefinido`, pero no me funciona, quiero saber **PORQUE** me ocurre el error, sé que puedo hacerlo con ***ES6 como parámetro por defecto***, pero quiero saber por qué sucede esto.

```js
Number.multiplos = function(numero,max){ 
  var multiplos = [];
  var limite = max > 100 ? 100 : max || 0; // Si max es mayor que 100 se asignará hasta el limite que es 100, si no se le asignará el parámetro max, en caso de que max no este definido será 0, pero no me funciona
  if(max === 0) return ('El parámetro max no está definido.');
};

var k = Number.multiplos(4,0);
var k2 = Number.multiplos(16); // Al NO pasarle el parámetro max, deberia ser como predeterminado 0, pero no lo es, por qué?
console.log('Le paso 0 como parámetro y si funciona: ' + k);

console.log('Si no le paso le paso el 0, no me funciona: ' + k2);
```

Comment: El problema es que estas comparando "max === 0" y cuando invocas la función sin asignar max toma el valor undefined. Creo que lo que intentabas hacer es if(limite === 0), ya que en ese caso limite tomó el valor 0 dada la condición (max || 0) que para max = undefined evalua a 0

Comment: Estás asignando el valor que quieres a la variable `lmite`, pero luego compruebas `max === 0`, por lo tanto si a la función no le pasas un 0, nunca te va a entrar en esa condición.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta con hacer un console.log a `max` dentro de tu método para obtener la respuesta.

`max` nunca lo estás igualando a nada en caso de que no venga, es decir solo obtienes su valor del parametro, al no pasarlo, obviamente es `undefined` como es en el segundo caso.

Más bien en tu caso me parece que la variable que tendrías que verificar sería limite

```
if(limite === 0) return ('El parámetro max no está definido.');
```

Comment: Gracias Sr1871 !!